# Cannot bookmark a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a JSP page I'm using within the struts framework. When I navigate through my pages of my web app using buttons on a menu bar, it navigates properly and I can access each of the pages (page1.do, page2.do) without any problems. When I bookmark one of the pages (page1.do) and attempt to go to the bookmark, I get an error.

**Request[/adminmanagement] does not contain handler parameter named directive**

If I manually type in the directive stuff "page1.do?directive=init", I have no problem accessing the page.

Here is my struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
"struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="FileUploadForm" type="net.cmpny.cc.forms.FileUploadForm"/>
</form-beans>
<global-exceptions>
</global-exceptions>
<global-forwards>
    <forward name="init"  path="/page1.do?directive=init"/>
</global-forwards>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/adminmanagement"
            type="net.cmpny.cc.action.Page1Action"
            parameter="directive">
<forward name="admin" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/Page1.jsp" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

Is there a way of adding the 'directive=init' automatically or forwarding to that page?

I was going to write a filter, but I feel like there's a better/cleaner way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: struts is terrible, GWT handles stuff like this transparently.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson - I don't think struts to GWT is a fair comparison. Struts framework is there to simplify servlets whereas GWT relates to Ajax implementations.

Comment: You don't 'bookmark JSP' pages (in Struts), you bookmark url requests, that correspond to '.do' URLs. JPS is used to show the result. And I'm not nitpicking, it's important to understand this.

Comment: @CoolBeans Struts **complicates** Servlets not the other way around. RESTlet or RESTEasy simplifies Servlets.

Comment: @Jarrod, IMO the comments are to be directed at the issue, not your opinion about the framework under question. Not everybody has the freedom to choose what they're coding in, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 4):

A forward won't change the address in the URL bar. You need to do a redirect:

```
<forward name="init" path="/page1.do?directive=init" redirect="true"/>
```